# HibernateTemplate Save Not Throwing Exception when trying to insert duplicate Key row

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, orm

I m using Spring's HibernateDAOSupport class to handle my DAO.
my problem is that when I use getHibernateSupport().save(order) when order already exist in the database, it just update the database row instead of throwing some kind of Exception.

my Hibernate hbm.xml file is :

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.shopping.db.CustomerOrder" table="CUSTOMERORDER" schema="PUBLIC">
    <id name="orderID" type="long">
        <column name="ORDERID" length="50" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="customer" class="com.shopping.db.Customer" fetch="select">
        <column name="USERNAME" length="50" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="status" type="string">
        <column name="STATUS" length="50" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="totalCost" type="float">
        <column name="TOTALCOST" precision="0" scale="0" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="orderDate" type="java.sql.Date">
        <column name="ORDERDATE" not-null="true" />
    </property>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

my DAO code is :

```
public void createDBOrder(CustomerOrder order, List<OrderItem> orderItems) 
{
  getHibernateTemplate().save(order);
  for (OrderItem item : orderItems) 
  {
    getHibernateTemplate().save(item);
  }
  getHibernateTemplate().flush();
}
```

my test method is as follow:

```
@Test
 public void testCreateDBOrder() 
 {
  int ordersCount = countRowsInTable("CUSTOMERORDER");
  int orderItemsCount = countRowsInTable("ORDERITEM");
  // Check for row count before insertion.
  assertEquals(1, ordersCount);
  assertEquals(1, orderItemsCount);

  CustomerOrder order = new CustomerOrder(3, dataAccessObject
  .getCustomerByName("Oussama"), "PENDING", 200, new Date(new Long(
"61191781200000")));
  OrderItem item = new OrderItem(333, dataAccessObject.getProductByID("Apple iPhone"),       order, 3);
  OrderItem item2 = new OrderItem(444, dataAccessObject.getProductByID("DV2000"), order, 2);
  List<OrderItem> items = new ArrayList<OrderItem>();
  items.add(item);
  items.add(item2);
  dataAccessObject.createDBOrder(order, items);
  ordersCount = countRowsInTable("CUSTOMERORDER");
  orderItemsCount = countRowsInTable("ORDERITEM");
  // Check for row count after insertion.
  assertEquals(2, ordersCount);
  assertEquals(3, orderItemsCount);
  assertEquals(3, dataAccessObject.getOrderByID(3).getOrderID());
  assertEquals(2, dataAccessObject.getOrderItemByOrderID(3).size());

  order.setStatus("SHIPPED");

  // Check for creating a order with the same ID.
  dataAccessObject.createDBOrder(order, items);
  assertEquals("SHIPPED", dataAccessObject.getOrderByID(3).getStatus());

  ordersCount = countRowsInTable("CUSTOMERORDER");
  // Check for row count after insertion.
  //assertEquals(3, ordersCount);
 }
```

Why is getHibernateTemplate().save() is just updating the database row instead if throwing an exception because of primary key already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `save` is ingored, because you are saving the same instance of `CustomerOrder` which already have been saved (i.e. a persistent object). If you try to save the different instance (i.e. a transient object) with the same id, you'll get an exception.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. I used a different instance and I got an exception. Interesting!!!